# Is the python library called request only for web url or also for local html file?

Tags: python

I can read the HTML file using

```
   file.read()
```

for web

```
   requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

I think like it is possible to use "requests.get()" for local HTML file

or

just use the "file.read()"

Answer (score 2):

The requests package is used for fetching data from webservers. It does not matter if that webserver is running locally or on the internet, as long as it is running, you can fetch it and send requests to it.

In your example, if the html file is being served locally, like say on `localhost:1234`, then you can fetch it. If it is not being served, then you cannot request it and will have to read it as a file.

Edit: Adding Sadan's comment

> Also worth noting, requests has nothing to do with HTML files, it can fetch any file in this manner

Comment: Also worth noting, `requests` has nothing to do with HTML files, it can fetch any file in this manner